# Formatting smtp message header fields in Ruby

Tags: ruby, smtp

I'm trying to create a normal smtp message in Ruby:

```
def send_email(msg, to)
    require 'net/smtp'
    require 'tlsmail'

    from = 'user@gmail.com'
    p = hmhmm

    msgstr = <<-END_OF_MESSAGE
    From: User <user@gmail.com>
    To: Jensa <jensa11.11.1@gmail.com>
    Subject: Titel

    Hej PÅ dig. Inte under.   # <- swedish ;)
    END_OF_MESSAGE

    Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

    Net::SMTP.start('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'gmail.com', from, p, :login) do |smtp|
        smtp.send_message msgstr, from, to
    end
    puts "message sent"
end
```

The message is sent, but all the data except the "TO" address ends up in the "FROM" field of the message, like this:

```
FROM: User <user@gmail.com> To: Jensa Subject: Titel Hej PÅ dig. Inte under.<user@gmail.com>
Date: 9 February 2012 14.36.03 CET
```

There's nothing in the message body.

When I add a '\n' after "Titel", then all the text after is placed in the message as it should:

```
From:   User <user@gmail.com> To: Jensa Subject: Titel <user@gmail.com>
Date:   9 februari 2012 14.36.03 CET

      Hej PÅ dig. Inte under.
```

But still the "TO" address is not visible and it's all in the FROM field.

What's the problem?

Comment: Is your "to" object an array?

Comment: FWIW, I find [Pony](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pony/1.4/frames) to be an exceptionally easy way to send email in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You MUST use a CRLF to separate each line.

I guess your lines are currently only being separated by either "\r" or "\n" - not both. Try:

```
msgstr = [
  "From: User <user@gmail.com>",
  "To: Jensa <jensa11.11.1@gmail.com>",
  "Subject: Titel",
  "",
  "Hej PÅ dig. Inte under."   # <- swedish ;)
].join("\r\n")
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked: From: User <user@gmail.com>\r\nTo: Jensa <jensa11.11.1@gmail.com>\r\nSubject: Titel\n  Why do I have to explicitly write those characters? I've seen no examples where they do. Usually they do just as I did with just hitting enter.

Comment: RFC2822 states "A line is a series of characters that is delimited with the two characters carriage-return and line-feed;" -- The main reason for that is to prevent ambiguity. Most operating systems use CR or LF to delimit lines. Some use CR, some use LF and some use both together to separate a line. Using both in emails makes it a lot easier for a program to interpret a new line on all of those operating systems. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline